# Since Control.CreateChildControls is marked as protected internal, it should not be visible inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance

I can’t figure out why Control.CreateChildControls is visible in web page’s code-behind class. Namely, Control.CreateChildControls is defined as `protected internal`, which means that method is visible only to derived classes located inside the same assembly as Control class. So how is that possible since as as far as I know, web-page class is not compiled into same assembly  as Control class ( System.Web.dll )?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the wording of 'protected internal' is misleading. It means 'protected' **or** 'internal' and not 'protected' **and** 'internal'.

In your %program files%\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc#\Specifications\1033, you have the C# reference manual, this is at section 1.6.2.

Therefore a derived class can use it.

Answer (score 2):

I find it very unhelpful to characterize the difference as between "protected and internal" vs "protected or internal". Which is "protected internal"?

You could say "protected internal is the least restrictive combination of protected **and** internal, therefore it means 'protected **and** internal'".

You could also say "protected internal restricts access to derived members **or** assembly members, therefore it means 'protected **or** internal'".

Yuck.

The better way to think about it is:

- the default accessibility of a member is "private" -- the smallest possible accessibility domain
- a modifier enlarges the accessibility domain of a member
- therefore protected internal enlarges the accessibility domain twice, once to derived members, and once to assembly members.

For more thoughts on this see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/04/24/why-can-t-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class-part-three.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `Page` class inherits from `Control`, which are both in the System.Web.UI namespace, and both in the System.Web assembly.